# Is Creality Ender 3 V2 Supposed To Come With Board V 4.2.2?

Tags: creality-ender-3, firmware, stepper-driver, creality

I recently purchased a Creality Ender 3 V2 ~1 month ago, and just yesterday installed a BLTouch. When looking at the motherboard, I noticed my board version is 4.2.2. Isn't the Ender 3 V2 supposed to come with a V 4.2.7 board? Did Creality mistakenly include the wrong board with my printer?

I did some googling but couldn't find a definitive answer. If anyone can, please let me know. My plan (if there was a mistake) is to email Creality customer service, but if any of you have a better suggestion, I'm all ears.

PS: I purchased this directly from Creality website, not Amazon or any other marketplace. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are shipping the v2 with the 4.2.2 board.  My understanding is that the 4.2.7 board has a change in the stepper driver pinout but is otherwise the same as 4.2.2.  The change in the pinout allowed them to change the stepper driver package as the stepper driver vendor appears to be changing that spec.  I've used both boards in my V2 with no discernable difference.